# Laptop powers up just no BIOS

Tags: laptop, motherboard, hardware-failure

I have a laptop that you can power up and fans come on and stuff but getting no POST on start up. Does this mean the motherboard probably went bad?

Comment: Do you get video output if you connect a monitor to the VGA port?

Comment: Nope. Nothing on VGA

Comment: more information would be nice. What kind of laptop? How old is it? Do you have any other information on it?

Answer (score 0):

Several things can cause this.

1. corrupt/faulty cmos (bios)
2. Bad memory module
3. Dead video chip
4. Bad motherboard or component on or attached to the motherboard.

First thing to try is a hard reset:

With the laptop powered off disconnect the AC cord and remove the main battery, hold the power button down for a full 30 seconds, connect ac cord Only, power up and see if it will post.

If this does not get a post, try removing the memory module(s) and re-seat them, if this does not help and you have more than 1 memory module installed try each memory module one at a time.

If none of this helps it is a more serious issue and most likely a completely corrupt bios or faulty motherboard or hardware attached to the motherboard.

Comment: Is there a way to reset cmos?

Comment: That is what the hard reset does.